# Assigning date field from dynamic context to string value in C#

Tags: c#, angular

I have come across this scenario where an API call is done from an angular service.

```
From angular Service:
    param = {
        date:"2018-10-10T17:03:38.000Z",
        id:"1234"
    }
    //...
    this.http.post(url, param).map(res => res.json()) // call to an MVC API

//MVC API
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult UpdateDate(dynamic context)
{
   string id = context.id;   //stores value as is
   string isoDate = context.date; 
   // iso formatted date string converts back to the following format
   //"10/10/2018 15:20:55"
}
```

isoDate field now have "10/10/2018 15:20:55" instead of original value "2018-10-10T17:03:38.000Z"

Any idea?

I came up with the work around is pass the date with suffix and prefix as follows
"|2018-10-10T17:03:38.000Z|" and replaced "|" with empty string once the value of isoDate is assigned.
This seems to be a hack still but works.

Just wanted to know the inside why this happens. 
Thank you.

Comment: First thing that comes to my mind is that wy are you using dynamics, while you can create proper object?

Comment: It is just a string you are passing, there is no way it could be converted in such a weird way.

Comment: I exactly thought the same. I expected to be the same string as passed,
when I did debug, I did see the actual iso datetime in the context object,
when I assigned the value to a variable, the variable completely changed to different format.

Answer (score 0):

The only real *primitive types* in json are `strings`, `numbers`, and `booleans` so conversion to `dynamic` (*expando object*) can be done only for those types. Everything else passed in as `string` (like your ISO8601 formatted date time) stays as `string`.

If you want conversion to a `DateTime` you would have to use a strongly typed model so that the deserializer (*json.net by default for web-api*) will attempt to parse the incoming string value to a `DateTime` type. Using a strong typed model is recommended as there is less chance of naming errors at run time (*because you would catch those at compile time*) and you can validate the model with model validation annotations like `RequiredAttribute`.

See also [JSON Data Types](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_datatypes.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same error today.

Inspecting the property of the dynamic object that contains the ISO string date, I saw that it was already converted to an object that contained a `Value` property that was a Date object (somne implicit conversion takes place, that's for sure).

[image]

In the image, `parametros` is a dynamic object and `dataPartida` the property that was a ISO date string sent as a POST body payload from Postman.

To solve my problem, I did:

```
string dataPartida = parametros["dataPartida"].Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
```

Hope it helps!